# Calculate difference between two datetime excluding weekends

Tags: php, date

For example 
02-11-2018 03:00pm - 05-11-2018 11:00am should be 2hrs.
Because 3rd and 4th are weekends.

```
$date1 = "2018-03-01 11:12:45"; 
$date2 = "2018-03-04 15:37:04";  
$date1Timestamp = strtotime($date1); 
$date2Timestamp = strtotime($date2); 
$difference = $date2Timestamp - $date1Timestamp; 
echo $difference;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Kindly add your latest code attempts to the question, so that we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I edited the post

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Generally when you post an example, you also post what the expected result is. Maybe you should pick dates that is closer to each other and give us what the expected result is supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to create UNIX timestamps for the two date/times you want to compare. These timestamps will represent the number of seconds between the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) and the time specified. Since they will both be in seconds, it makes it very easy to calculate the seconds between the two timestamps:

```
<?php

//set start time and end time - mktime(hour, minute, second, month, day, year)
$startTime = mktime(15, 0, 0, 11, 2, 2018); // 2-11-2018 3:00PM
$endTime = mktime(11, 0, 0, 11, 5, 2018); // 5-11-2018 11:00AM

//calculate total number of seconds between two date/times
$totalSeconds = $endTime - $startTime;

//apply whatever other math you need...

?>
```

As far as accounting for weekends and business hours, you will need to get creative with determining how many weekend days exist between the two date/times and what hours fall within business hours on business days. The PHP manual for [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions will come in handy. The following code produces the results you are looking for:

```
<?php
//set business start and end hours
$businessStartHour = 10; //10 AM
$businessEndHour = 16; //4 PM

//set weekend days
$arrWeekendDays = array(6,0); //numeric representations of Saturday (6) and Sunday (0)

//set start and end dates and times
//2-11-2018 3 PM
$startHour = 15;
$startMinute = 0;
$startSecond = 0;
$startMonth = 11;
$startDay = 2;
$startYear = 2018;

//5-11-2018 11 AM
$endHour = 11;
$endMinute = 0;
$endSecond = 0;
$endMonth = 11;
$endDay = 5;
$endYear = 2018;

//create UNIX timestamps
$startTime = mktime($startHour, $startMinute, $startSecond, $startMonth, $startDay, $startYear);
$endTime = mktime($endHour, $endMinute, $endSecond, $endMonth, $endDay, $endYear);

//ensure $endTime is greater than $startTime
if($startTime >= $endTime){
    //invalid start and end datetimes
    die("Invalid start and end datetimes.");
}

//calculate eligible seconds from partial time on first and last day
$totalSeconds = 0;

$currentTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $startMonth, $startDay, $startYear); //beginning of $startTime day
$lastFullDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $endMonth, $endDay, $endYear); //beginning of $endTime day

$startingBusinessTime = mktime($businessStartHour, 0, 0, $startMonth, $startDay, $startYear);
$endingBusinessTime = mktime($businessEndHour, 0, 0, $endMonth, $endDay, $endYear);

if($startTime < $startingBusinessTime){
    $startTime = $startingBusinessTime;
}
if($endTime > $endingBusinessTime){
    $endTime = $endingBusinessTime;
}

if($currentTime == $lastFullDay){
    //$startTime and $endTime occur on the same day
    if($endTime > $startTime){
        $totalSeconds += ($endTime - $startTime);
    }
}else{
    //$startTime and $endTime do not occur on the same day
    $startingBusinessTime = mktime($businessStartHour, 0, 0, $endMonth, $endDay, $endYear);
    $endingBusinessTime = mktime($businessEndHour, 0, 0, $startMonth, $startDay, $startYear);
    if($endingBusinessTime > $startTime){
        $totalSeconds += ($endingBusinessTime - $startTime);
    }
    if($endTime > $startingBusinessTime){
        $totalSeconds += ($endTime - $startingBusinessTime);
    }
}

//calculate eligible seconds from all full days in between start day and end day
$fullDayBusinessSeconds = (($businessEndHour - $businessStartHour) * 3600);

//set $currentTime to beginning of first full day
$nextDay = $currentTime + (26 * 3600); //add 26 hours to $currentTime to get into the next day, compensating for possible daylight savings
$currentTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $nextDay), date('j', $nextDay), date('Y', $nextDay));

while($currentTime < $lastFullDay){
    //determine if $currentTime is a weekday
    if(!in_array(date('w', $currentTime), $arrWeekendDays)){
        //it's a business day, add all business seconds to $totalSeconds
        $totalSeconds += $fullDayBusinessSeconds;
    }
    //increment $currentTime to beginning of next day
    $nextDay = $currentTime + (26 * 3600); //add 26 hours to $currentTime to get into the next day, compensating for possible daylight savings
    $currentTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $nextDay), date('j', $nextDay), date('Y', $nextDay));
}

echo "Total eligible time between start time and end time: " . $totalSeconds . " seconds (" . convertSecToTime($totalSeconds) . ")";

function convertSecToTime($sec) 
 {
  $date1 = new DateTime("@0");
  $date2 = new DateTime("@$sec");
  $interval =  date_diff($date1, $date2);
  return $interval->format('%y Years, %m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
  // convert into Days, Hours, Minutes
  // return $interval->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds'); 
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly have a look at this precise php function returning days count with weekends excluded.

```
$start= "2018-03-01 11:12:45"; 
$end= "2018-04-01 15:37:04";

echo Count_Days_Without_Weekends($start, $end);

function Count_Days_Without_Weekends($start, $end){
    $days_diff = floor(((abs(strtotime($end) - strtotime($start))) / (60*60*24)));
    $run_days=0;
    for($i=0; $i<=$days_diff; $i++){
        $newdays = $i-$days_diff;
        $futuredate = strtotime("$newdays days");
        $mydate = date("F d, Y", $futuredate);
        $today = date("D", strtotime($mydate));             
        if(($today != "Sat") && ($today != "Sun")){
            $run_days++;
        }
    }
return $run_days;
}
```

Try it out, it really works..